# Aborting a GRPC Server Stream Connection in GRPC Ruby Client

Tags: ruby, grpc

Consider a grpc defined service as:

```
rpc :StreamingEvents, StreamingEventRequest, stream(StreamingEventResponse)
```

And utilizing a client to connect to this service similarly to this:

```
call = stub.streaming_events(StreamingEventRequest.new)

call.each do |response|
  pp response
end
```

If we were to spawn the call in a separate thread, what would the proper way to handle terminating a grpc connection that runs forever that we no longer want to utilize anymore? Are there any connection or flow control methods to be able to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dug around the source and pulled apart how all this works. If you want to do any advance stuff with flow control, you have to pass in the `return_op` parameter to receive an operator object to control the flow. Here is some sample code:

Passing block methodology:

```
op = stub.streaming_events(StreamingEventRequest.new, return_op: true) do |response|
  pp response
end

t = Thread.new do
  op.execute
rescue GRPC::Cancelled => e
  puts "this will terminate with an exception when we hit cancel - #{e}"
end

# controls for the operation
op.status
op.cancelled?
op.cancel # terminates connection and raises GRPC::Cancelled in the thread.
```

Enumerator example:

```
op = stub.streaming_events(StreamingEventRequest.new, return_op: true)

t = Thread.new do
  call = op.execute
  call.each do |response|
    pp response
  end
rescue GRPC::Cancelled => e
  puts "this will terminate with an exception when we hit cancel - #{e}"
end

# controls for the operation
op.status
op.cancelled?
op.cancel # terminates connection and raises GRPC::Cancelled in the thread.
```